# Allow proxy server to accept random number routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

Okay so i have created a proxy server to connect to supremenewyork.com because of cors. Certain routes are static like /shop or /mobile_stock.json, but some other routes are dynamic. After i go to /mobile_stock.json, i parse a specific value from there that i then use in the next route call /shop/${item_id}.json . But when I go through my proxy server, which I have to, I get 404. This item_id changes all the time. Any way to do this, here is my code:

```
const itemLink = `/shop/${desired_item_id}.json`;

    const itemPage = await helperFunctions.redirectTo(
        itemLink, 
        DELAY, 
        "Successfully connected to product page!", 
        "Error accessing Supreme site, retrying...");
```

Here is helperFunctions.js

```
const session = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://botapi.supremenewyork.com:8050`,
  });

// timer function for delays
const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// function for simple get requests
const redirectTo = async (redirectLink, delay, successfullMessage, errorMessage) => {

    while(true){

        try{
            const getRedirect = await session.get(redirectLink);

            if(getRedirect.status === 200){
                if(successfullMessage != null){
                    console.log(successfullMessage);
                }
                await timer(delay);
                return getRedirect;
            }

            else {
                console.log(errorMessage)
                await timer(delay);
            }
        }

        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            await timer(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my server.js which creates the proxy server:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.options('*', cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  request(
    { url: 'https://supremenewyork.com' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
      }
      res.send(body);
    }
  )
});
app.get('/mobile_stock.json', (req, res) => {
  request(
    { url: 'https://supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
      }
      res.send(body);
    }
  )
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8050;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, been making a lot of progress and learning a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route you can define like this:

```
app.get('/:jsonfilename', (req, res) => {
  let jsonName = req.params.jsonfilename
  request(
    { url: 'https://supremenewyork.com/'+jsonName },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
      }
      res.send(body);
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Still no luck, I see what you are saying though. I still end up getting 404, and callLogController is not defined, do i need to import something?

Comment: Okay, thought so. I got rid of that, still 404, but then I added /shop/:jsonfilename and that fixed 404, but now its just straight up not connecting with no error code... I'm trying to go to https://supremenewyork.com/shop/172991.json

Comment: Can you share the log of server that is coming on the request

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work! Thank you so much. I just had made it `app.get('/shop/:jsonfilename')` and then url: `'https://supremenewyork.com/shop/'+jsonName`